# How to safely prevent/terminate a hanging Win32/COM thread without killing the process?

Tags: multithreading, winapi, com, thread-safety

How can you invoke a buggy out-of-process COM server that causes its clients to randomly hang when calling its methods (*without* killing the client process)?

Consider a process that spawns a worker thread, initializes [STA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms809971(v=msdn.10)#behavior-of-the-com-threading-models) COM, obtains a buggy COM object, and then begins invoking its methods until they hang.  How can the hang be prevented or interrupted?

A naive solution is to call `TerminateThread` if the thread doesn't respond within a certain time. But Microsoft [commands here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/learnwin32/initializing-the-com-library#uninitializing-the-com-library) that every thread that calls `CoInitializeEx` must call `CoUninitialize` or risk leaking resources, and `TerminateThread` skips this.  (Side note: is `CoUninitialize` unnecessary if the thread is terminated?)

If this is literally unsolvable with public Windows APIs, I'm open to undocumented/internal means and OS tampering.  Is it possible to substitute something for what `Ole32.dll` intends to return to the thread?  Is this even done in `Ole32.dll`?  Or to cause Windows to awaken the thread with bogus data?  (Assume other threads also use their own STA COM).

Comment: There is really nothing you can do besides kill the client process and terminate the hung thread.

Comment: But the question is, is terminating the thread a sufficient substitute for `CoUninitialize`?  Or do resources leak?

Comment: Of course they leak, `TerminatingThread()` is a brute force operation that doesn't allow for any kind of cleanup at all. That is why you should never use it unless you have no other choice. And a thread hung on a buggy COM object counts as such a case.

Comment: Two options. Put the COM object in a separate process to provide sufficient isolation. Or stop using it and replace it with code that works.

Comment: If the buggy COM object is housed in an out-of-proc server (as you seem to suggest), then you can make [asynchronous COM calls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/com/making-and-processing-asynchronous-calls) on it. Those calls can be canceled, say on a timeout.

Comment: Or you can use CoCancelCall to cancel a pending call.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That isn't apparent, as `TerminateThread` doesn't specify what happens to thread-local storage at termination, nor when the last thread handle is closed.  Also `CoCancelCall` and async COM calls seem like additional options.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thank you.  How does `ICancelMethodCalls::Cancel` /`CoCancelCall` work under-the-hood in the event of successful cancellation?  Is there any way I can manually simulate this / signal whichever object Windows is waiting on?

Comment: @alexchandel `TerminateThread()` does not allow TLS data to be cleaned up. It also does not close the `HANDLE`, the caller still has to do that separately. Terminating a thread and closing a handle are two different things.

Comment: It cancels the outstanding RPC request. I don't know what you mean about "manually simulating" it. If you want to test cancellation, then just issue a call and cancel it immediately.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I realize, but its doc simply doesn't say what happens in those cases.

Comment: @RaymondChen But since [the behavior of a cancel request is entirely at the discretion of the implementer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/objidl/nf-objidl-icancelmethodcalls-cancel#remarks), if the object server never calls `CoTestCancel` or is ignoring all cancellation requests, is there a way to simulate a successful cancelation & return control to the thread?  Even by meddling with the proxy object's internals?

Comment: The call is indeed canceled at the proxy layer, and the client call will return with some RPC error code (I forget what). Meanwhile, the cancel request is delivered to the server, and what the server does with the cancel request is up to the server. In the worst case, the server will ignore the cancel and run the operation to completion and return a result that gets ignored. But that's okay. Your client call returned hours ago with a "canceled" error code. If the server wants to waste CPU, that's the server's problem.